# How to remove empty when grouping?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

Using knowledge from https://stackoverflow.com/a/67741552/11928194, I came up with the following XSLT:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006"
    xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration='yes' method='xml' version='1.0' />
    <xsl:template match='/'>
        <edi856>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="/ns0:X12_00401_856/ns0:HLLoop1" group-starting-with="/ns0:X12_00401_856/ns0:HLLoop1[ns0:HL03='Q']">
                <hlq json:Array='true'>
                    <hlqId>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/ns0:TSD/TSD01"/>
                    </hlqId>
                    <xsl:variable name="hlq" select="current-group()" />
                    <xsl:variable name="hlq-id" select="$hlq/ns0:TSD/TSD01" />
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[position() gt 1]" group-starting-with="/ns0:X12_00401_856/ns0:HLLoop1[ns0:HL/HL03='I']">
                        <hli json:Array='true'>
                            <hlqId>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$hlq-id"/>
                            </hlqId>
                            <hliId>
                                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/ns0:LIN/LIN03"/>
                            </hliId>
                        </hli>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </hlq>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </edi856>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I use it with the below input (Input#1):

```xml
<ns0:X12_00401_856 xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006">
    <ns0:HLLoop1>
        <ns0:HL>
            <HL03>Q</HL03>
        </ns0:HL>
        <ns0:TSD>
            <TSD01>DELIVERY1</TSD01>
        </ns0:TSD>
    </ns0:HLLoop1>
    <ns0:HLLoop1>
        <ns0:HL>
            <HL03>I</HL03>
        </ns0:HL>
        <ns0:LIN>
            <LIN03>asnLineItem1</LIN03>
        </ns0:LIN>
    </ns0:HLLoop1>
</ns0:X12_00401_856>
```

Output is generated as (Actual#1):

```xml
<edi856 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006"
    xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
    <hlq json:Array="true">
        <hlqId>DELIVERY1</hlqId>
        <hli json:Array="true">
            <hlqId>DELIVERY1</hlqId>
            <hliId/>
        </hli>
        <hli json:Array="true">
            <hlqId>DELIVERY1</hlqId>
            <hliId>asnLineItem1</hliId>
        </hli>
    </hlq>
</edi856>
```

I expect the output to have only 1 `hli` (Expected#1):

```xml
<edi856 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006"
    xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
    <hlq json:Array="true">
        <hlqId>DELIVERY1</hlqId>
        <hli json:Array="true">
            <hlqId>DELIVERY1</hlqId>
            <hliId>asnLineItem1</hliId>
        </hli>
    </hlq>
</edi856>
```

When I remove the HLLLoop1 with HL03=I, I expect `hli` to not exist in the output, however it is still present.

Input#2:

```xml
<ns0:X12_00401_856 xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006">
    <ns0:HLLoop1>
        <ns0:HL>
            <HL03>Q</HL03>
        </ns0:HL>
        <ns0:TSD>
            <TSD01>DELIVERY1</TSD01>
        </ns0:TSD>
    </ns0:HLLoop1>
</ns0:X12_00401_856>
```

Actual#2:

```xml
<edi856 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006"
    xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
    <hlq json:Array="true">
        <hlqId>DELIVERY1</hlqId>
        <hli json:Array="true">
            <hlqId>DELIVERY1</hlqId>
            <hliId/>
        </hli>
    </hlq>
</edi856>
```

Expected#2:

```xml
<edi856 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006"
    xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
    <hlq json:Array="true">
        <hlqId>DELIVERY1</hlqId>
    </hlq>
</edi856>
```

What am I missing here to match my expectations?

Comment: Can you explain the grouping you want to achieve? Do you want to output items that don't match the `group-starting-with` pattern?

Comment: @MartinHonnen according to the given input, only the 2nd `hli` should've been generated

Comment: @MartinHonnen I've added the expected output and another example

Comment: That is not an answer to my question. Is that your first use of  `group-starting-with`? Are you aware it builds groups even for non-matching items? It is not clear whether you need `for-each-group` and `group-starting-with`, try to explain which elements you want to select and/or group and output without relying solely on code you saw in another answer (where the input might be more regular than in your case).

Comment: A simplified example, showing ONLY what's necessary to demonstrate the problem, would be useful.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I'm the asker on that other answer as well. I believe the inputs are similar because I built it exactly for this use case. I don't understand how and why they are different.

Comment: @michael.hor257k done

Comment: @michael.hor257k I believe if I simplify this even further, I'd end up with input similar to my linked question, with `ns0:HLLoop1` replacing `Item` and the inner element `ns0:HL/HL03` replacing the `type` attribute. While @MartinHonnen 's solution works perfectly, I'd still like to understand why it requires an additional `if` when compared to the linked answer.

Comment: Ideally, you would enable us to reproduce the problem using a single level of grouping and an input similar to the simple example used in your other question. I am afraid I don't have the time or the patience to go through what you have now.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Understandable.

Comment: The reason is given in my answer: "The difference between these samples and the previous one is that there your grouping population always started with a matching item". So remember or learn that `for-each-group select="$seq" group-starting-with="foo"` with `$seq` being e.g. `<bar/><bar/><foo/><bar/><bar/>` forms two groups, the first one with the non-matching `bar` elements, the second one started with the matching `foo` and including the following `bar` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps wrapping the content of your inner `for-each-group` into an  `<xsl:if test="self::ns0:HLLoop1[ns0:HL/HL03='I']">...</xsl:if>` helps but I am not sure I have understood the structure of the input data and the wanted grouping requirement.

And I think for the outer `for-each-group` you rather want `group-starting-with="ns0:HLLoop1[ns0:HL/HL03='Q']"` but there as well you need to wrap the body of the `for-each-group` into an `<xsl:if test="self::ns0:HLLoop1[ns0:HL/HL03='Q']">..</xsl:if>` to output results only for matching groups and not for the one `for-each-group` gives you for non-matching items.

So the template would be

```
<xsl:template match='/'>
    <edi856>
        <xsl:variable name="bsn02" select="/ns0:X12_00401_856/ns0:BSN/BSN02" />
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/ns0:X12_00401_856/ns0:HLLoop1" group-starting-with="ns0:HLLoop1[ns0:HL/HL03='Q']">
            <xsl:if test="self::ns0:HLLoop1[ns0:HL/HL03='Q']">
                <hlq json:Array='true'>
                    <hlqId>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/ns0:TSD/TSD01"/>
                    </hlqId>
                    <bsn02>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$bsn02"/>
                    </bsn02>
                    <xsl:variable name="hlq" select="current-group()" />
                    <xsl:variable name="hlq-id" select="$hlq/ns0:TSD/TSD01" />
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[position() gt 1]" group-starting-with="ns0:HLLoop1[ns0:HL/HL03='I']">
                        <xsl:if test="self::ns0:HLLoop1[ns0:HL/HL03='I']">
                            <hli json:Array='true'>
                                <hlqId>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$hlq-id"/>
                                </hlqId>
                                <bsn02>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$bsn02"/>
                                </bsn02>
                                <hliId>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/ns0:LIN/LIN03"/>
                                </hliId>
                            </hli>                            
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </hlq>                    
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </edi856>
</xsl:template>
```

The difference between these samples and the previous one is that there your grouping population always started with a matching item (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#xsl-for-each-group):

> If the group-starting-with attribute is present, then its value must
> be a pattern.
>
> The items in the population are examined in population order. If an
> item matches the pattern, or is the first item in the population, then
> a new group is created and the item becomes its first member.
> Otherwise, the item is appended to the same group as its preceding
> item within the population.